# Use user movement instead a click event to spin a bottle

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-10

I have an app for Windows Universal that rotate a bottle and stop it in a random possition. The thing is, it only needs a click and the bottle spin, I need something more natural, like the user itself rotate the bottle with a circular gesture on top of the bottle (see image bellow). I have the following code:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="spinrect">
        <DoubleAnimation To="360" RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
     Storyboard.TargetName="samplebottle"
     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" />
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
<Image x:Name="samplebottle" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Assets/Bottles/bottle-sample.png" PointerPressed="SpinMe">
   <Image.RenderTransform>
     <RotateTransform Angle="90"></RotateTransform>
   </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

an in the background I have this:

```
private async void SpinMe(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        spinrect.Resume();
        spinrect.Stop();
        spinrect.Begin();
        Random rad = new Random();
        await Task.Delay(rad.Next(2000, 4000));
        spinrect.Pause();
}
```

[image: Use user movement instead a click event]

Comment: +1 Sounds like a cool proj, might take a look at [UIElement.ManipulationInertiaStarting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationinertiastarting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and wish I had time to tinker.